# VBA does not recognize expressions

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

For better picture, current system is Windows 11 and Office 365.
I have a small VBA which should execute some SAP export.
The main problem is that excel does not recognize the VBA expressions.

```
Public Sub BlaBla()

Dim W_Ret As Boolean



W_Ret = Attach_Session("PMM600")
If Not W_Ret Then
    Exit Sub
End If


On Error GoTo myerr


fpath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\BlaBla\"
strDateStart = Format(Worksheets("Control").Range("B6"), "ddmmyyyy")
```

Unfortunately both of the expression ( fpath and strDateStart ) remains empty.
Please see screenshot of the Watches [Watches ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6GVx.jpg)

I think that could be caused by missing references in the VBA, but for me looks all fine.
Please see [References](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ew2Z8.jpg)

Any idea what can cause above issue ?

Comment: Set fpath  = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").....

Comment: @ΑΓΡΙΑΠΕΣΤΡΟΦΑ thats not it, `fpath` is meant to be a string. They're taking a value from the object and appending a string, and saving the result to `fpath`. In this case `Set` wouldn't be correct.

Comment: The obvious line that stands out to me is `On Error GoTo myerr`. If you remove that line, what happens?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with the information you have provided. How did you declare `fpath` and `strDateStart`?

Comment: at which point in your code did you set the breakpoint (or stepped to) in order to look at the current values of your variables?

Comment: you nailed it @Ron Rosenfeld, fpath and strDateStart stay empty because the lines after "on error" are in error and not executed. Only a small part of the code is shown, it probably starts with "option explicit".